# Using sprockets / asset pipeline with multiple asset directories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I'm currently designing an application in which users can choose a theme and publish their page.

In order to achieve this, I've organized my Ruby on Rails project in the following way:

```
> app
  > controllers
  > helpers
  > mailers
  > models
  > views
  > assets
    > stylesheets
      - style.scss
    > images
      - image.jpg
    > javascripts
  > themes
    > theme_1
      - layout.html.erb
      > assets
        > stylesheets
          - style.scss
        > images
          - image.jpg
        > javascripts
    > theme_2
    > ....
```

When using built-in helpers such as `stylesheet_link_tag` and `image_tag` in /app/themes/theme_1/layout.html.erb, I want these helpers to use the assets located in their own directory.

For example, when using the following code in /app/themes/theme_1/layout.html.erb:

```
<%= image_tag('image.jpg') %>
```

I want to show the image located at /app/themes/theme_1/assets/images/image.jpg and not the image located at /app/views/assets/images/image.jpg. The same goes for using `stylesheet_link_tag` and style.scss.

So basically, I want to know if there is - for example - a way to define a directory in which built-in helpers such as `stylesheet_link_tag` and `image_tag` will look, because at this moment I get conflicts when linking to assets that share their filename with other assets located in different folders.

Help is greatly appreciated, other ideas how I could go about doing this are very welcome as well.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to show the image located at /app/themes/theme_1/assets/images/image.jpg and not the image located at /app/views/assets/images/image.jpg.

I believe the more conventional approach for this would be to make folder(s) inside `app/assets/images` called `themes/theme_1` and then put your theme images in there.

Now you can use your `image_tag` like this

```
= image_tag('/themes/theme_1/image.jpg')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now while this does fix my problem, I'm still wondering if there is a solution where I can keep the theme assets contained in their own directory instead of making new directories in all the sub-directories inside `app/assets/` for each and every theme. I must admit that your example is probably the more conventional way, and I know sticking to conventions is the preferred way of doing things with Ruby on Rails but in my case I can think of a lot of advantages in terms of flexibility if I can keep the assets of my themes separated from the rest of my application.